# Update 2019 - How to Livestream your Android device camera video to html webpage

Tags: html, node.js, android-studio, socket.io, http-live-streaming

I have been searching for the solution to this problem and I can't find a simple way to connect my android device camera video and livestream the video to socket.io or any other easy server(heroku/firebase even) and then while that video is in the server, in real-time I want to display the video being shot from my android phone to my html webpage.

I have built a simple video chat app with socket.io and node.js/html which uses my webcam, but I am having a very difficult time replacing the webcam with what is being shot in real-time from my android phone. How do I do this? I would super appreciate any code examples that would be huge. I know others have this problem as well.

Here is my Server side code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

  app.use(express.static('public'));

   var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');

   });




io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('username', function(username) {
        socket.username = username;
        io.emit('is_online', ' <i>' + socket.username + ' join the chat..</i>');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(username) {
        io.emit('is_online', ' <i>' + socket.username + ' left the 
chat..</i>');
    })

    socket.on('chat_message', function(message) {
        io.emit('chat_message', '<strong>' + socket.username + '</strong>: ' + message);
    });

});

const server = http.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Here is my client-side html which views the webcam. I would love to replace the webcam with my android camera. So I am lost on the android side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>livestreams</title>
     <header>
        <h1>livestream</h1>
    </header>
     <img src="/images/sonoma_logo.png" id="logo" height="400" 
width="550">
    <style>
 /*   body {
  background-color: lightblue;
 }*/
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #5a7ddb ; padding: 3px; position: fixed; 
 bottom: 0; width: 100%; border-color: #000; border-top-style: solid; 
 border-top-width: 1px;}
        form input { border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 10px; width: 85%; margin-right: .5%; }
       form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: 
   none; padding: 10px; margin-left: 2%; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
     </style>
     <script src="../../socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
        <video  id="video" style="width:680px; height: 480px;" controls> 
      </video>
     <body>
      <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:40000px;">
       <ul id="messages"></ul>
      <form action="/" method="POST" id="chatForm">
         <input id="txt" autocomplete="off" autofocus="on" oninput="isTyping()" placeholder="type your message here..." /> 
     <button>Send</button>
      </form>
        <div/>


            <script>
       ///Position logo

     var ve =document.getElementById("logo");
       ve.style.position="absolute";
       ve.style.left = 700+'px';
       ve.style.top = 10+'px'; 

        var socket = io.connect();
        // submit text message without reload/refresh the page
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
            socket.emit('chat_message', $('#txt').val());
            $('#txt').val('');
            return false;
        });
        // append the chat text message
        socket.on('chat_message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(msg));
        });
        // append text if someone is online
        socket.on('is_online', function(username) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(username));
        });
        // ask username
        var username = prompt('Please tell me your name');
        socket.emit('username', username);











        ///////////////////////////////////////////////
           let constraintObj = { 
        audio: true, 
        video: { 
            facingMode: "user", 
            width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
            height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 } 
        } 
    }; 
    // width: 1280, height: 720  -- preference only
    // facingMode: {exact: "user"}
    // facingMode: "environment"

    //handle older browsers that might implement getUserMedia in some way
    if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
        navigator.mediaDevices = {};


        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraintObj) {
            let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
            if (!getUserMedia) {
                return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
            }
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraintObj, resolve, reject);
            });
        }
    }else{
        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        .then(devices => {
            devices.forEach(device=>{
                console.log(device.kind.toUpperCase(), device.label);
                //, device.deviceId
            })
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err.name, err.message);
        })
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
    .then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
        //connect the media stream to the first video element
        let video = document.querySelector('video');
        if ("srcObject" in video) {
            video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
        } else {
            //old version
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
        }

        video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {
            //show in the video element what is being captured by the webcam
            video.play();
        };

        //add listeners for saving video/audio
        let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
        let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
        let vidSave = document.getElementById('vid2');
        let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
        let chunks = [];

        start.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        })
        stop.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        });
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
            chunks.push(ev.data);
        }
        mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
            let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/mp4;' });
            chunks = [];
            let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            vidSave.src = videoURL;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) { 
        console.log(err.name, err.message); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Depends what you're going for, but I found this tutorial very useful when exploring capturing the video device: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: The problem is, how do I livestream the webcam so that another device/computer can view it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need html to include in this. You can use a library in java that is socket.io client java to get connected with your nodejs server.you can visit page https://socketio.github.io/socket.io-client-java/installation.html for this library Implementation and usage